# "To do not" phrase

Tags: phrase-usage

Is it possible that the phrase is correct?

"To do or to do not that is the question."

I know that the usual order would be:
"To do or not to do"

Comment: You can position an infinitive marker before or after the negation indicator (as ***not to do*** or ***to not do***), but putting it after the verb itself strikes me as somewhat archaic (as the "fossilised" imperative usage ***Fear not!***).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I don't think I would call the imperative usage fossilized. It's at least as recent as JFK. *My fellow Americans, ask not what your country can do for you, ask what you can do for your country.* You might say, though, that it has an elevated register.

Comment: Not sure if you can quote Shakespeare and improve on him at the same time. If you're quoting, that would call for the **not to be** form. Furthermore, the original line examines whether life is worth living, but apart from the fame, the phrase 'to be or not to be' is frankly confusing.

Comment: @ktm5124: Perhaps I'm using "fossilized" a bit loosely. But let's not forget that JFK was speaking over 50 years ago, in a highly stylised register, *and* in a context that gains "currency" by association with forms such as *I'll give you **not one but two** reasons to believe*. I can't imagine Trump today saying *Most mainstream news is biased! Believe it not!*

Comment: “Do. Or do not. There is no try."

Comment: @FumbleFingers, Thank you! To say the truth I hear a voice in my head just with the same intonation as "Fear not!".

Comment: @ktm5124, thank you for the example!

Comment: @YosefBaskin, I wasn't quoting.

Comment: Sorry, you are not quoting when you say ""To do or to do not that is the question"?

Comment: @Hot Licks: That's what I thought when I and [over 390,000 other people put ***Jedi knight*** on the UK 2001 census](https://www.theguardian.com/uk/datablog/interactive/2012/dec/11/census-religion). But despite our best efforts, we didn't succeed in getting official recognition for our faith. Which I suppose means if Yoda ever comes to visit his flock here on earth, we'll all be excommunicated for failing to honour our "One and only commandment".

Comment: @YosefBaskin, yes and no. Originally the phrase was different. And the intention was not to quote Shakespeare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no reason why "to do not" would be ungrammatical. In fact, there's a novel by Hemingway with the title: *To Have and Have Not*. The negative adverb, here, is placed after the infinitive.

While this shows that the phrase *to do not* is grammatical, it does not show that the phrase is idiomatic. In fact, I would recommend against using *to do not*. First, it does not have much precedent, as this [ngram search reveals](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=not+to+do%2Cto+do+not&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnot%20to%20do%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cto%20do%20not%3B%2Cc0). Second, it could easily be confused with the phrase *to do naught*. This play on words might be intentional in the phrase *to have not*, but not in your case.

Comment: Agreed - I wouldn't use the sentence on everyday base; but I needed some pathos or uncommon emphasize in the phrase. And thank you for the funny reference to naughty. : )